# Displaying multiple variables on single line?

Tags: java, stack, push, is-empty

So I'm doing a program which reads in a message up to 80 characters long and displays it back to the user using the push, pop, and isempty methods. The only problem is, a single variable will be printed on the line, so the backwards message goes vertically down the screen one letter at a time. The code is below, can someone tell me the correct command or what needs to be fixed?

```
public class StackUser

{
static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int length;
        int I = 0;
        char currChar;
        int Max = 80;
        myStack Placeholder;
        Placeholder = new myStack();

        System.out.println("Please enter any word or sentence up to a maximum of 80 characters long.");
        String userEnter = keyboard.nextLine();
        length = userEnter.length();
        if (length < Max)
            {

                while (I < length)
                    {
                        char res = userEnter.charAt(I); 
                        Placeholder.PushChar(res); 
                        I = I + 1;
                    }
            }   
        if (Max < length)
            {

                while (I < Max)
                    {
                        char res = userEnter.charAt(I);
                        Placeholder.PushChar(res);
                        I = I + 1;
                    }
            }
        while (Placeholder.IsEmpty() != true)
            {
                currChar = Placeholder.PopChar();
                System.out.println("Here is your message backwards:" + currChar);
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to print more than one thing on a line use `print` instead of `println`

Comment: you want to print your message formatted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use print instead of println:

```
    System.out.print("Here is your message backwards: ");
    while (Placeholder.IsEmpty() != true) {
        currChar = Placeholder.PopChar();
        System.out.print(currChar);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry, I didn't see you included that in your answer so I deleted the question. Will provide best answer when available, thank you.